# Adding Audio file from Drive to Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, audio, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

Google has somewhat recently rolled out the ability to insert audio files from your Drive into Slides with various playback options.

I cannot find any documentation on how to insert a file through Google Scripts but can do so going through the available menu options. I tried using the insertVideo method but got an error

"Exception: The parameters (DriveApp.File) don't match the method signature for SlidesApp.Slide.insertVideo."

Here is a general function I'm trying to get to work (NOOB disclaimer goes here):

```
function uploadAudioToCurrentSlide(){
   var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
   var currentSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
   var audioFile = DriveApp.getFileById('idofaudiofileindrive');
   currentSlide.insertVideo(audioFile);
   }
```

Any help is most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

- You want to insert a audio file in Google Drive to Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and workaround:

I think that the reason of your issue is that the file object is directly used to the method of `insertVideo`. The argument of `insertVideo` is the URL and the video object which is not the file object. By this, such error occurs.

- In the current stage, when the method of `insertVideo` is used, the video content is required to be the publicly shared YouTube URL.
- And also, it seems that the audio file cannot be directly inserted.

Unfortunately, it seems that these are the current specification. So as a workaround, how about the following flow?

1. At first, convert the audio file to a video file like MP4. As a test, this can be done at other site. But I'm not sure about the file type of your audio file.
2. Insert the converted MP4 file on Google Drive using Slides API.

When the Slides API is used, you can insert the video file in Google Drive to the Google Slides. In this sample script, "CreateVideoRequest" of the batchUpdate method of Slides API is used.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, [please enable Slides API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

```
function myFunction() {
  var fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID of the converted video file on Google Drive.

  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var currentSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  var resource = {requests: [{createVideo: {source: "DRIVE", id: fileId, elementProperties: {pageObjectId: currentSlide.getObjectId()}}}]};
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentation.getId());
}
```

#### Note:

- When you can upload the audio file to YouTube and publicly share it, you can use your script using the URL of the YouTube.

#### References:

- [insertVideo(videoUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertvideovideourl)- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [CreateVideoRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request?hl=ja#createvideorequest)

Comment: Thanks so much Tanaike! I will try out your work around for sure. You are correct with what I am trying to do. I wasn't sure if there was a method I was missing or some way to directly insert the audio similar to the insertVideo method.

Comment: @LD101 Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, the audio file cannot be directly inserted by the script. It seems that this is the current specification. If you tested this workaround and this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.